# Illustrated children's book series with Greek Mythology references

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, greek-myth

I'm trying to find a book series. I remember there were lot of Greek Mythology references including

- Medea in one of the books
- someone called Nico (or potentially that's Nico from Pharesee)
- the Clashing Rocks (potentially called "Holsteins" or "Holbeins" or "Hol-something"). A harpy (a little dragon like thing) was squashed between them.
- Ithaca (I think Ithaca was quite a significant place in these books)

I read this in mid-2000s.

I seem to remember some books being mostly words with occasional illustrations, and some books having a lot more illustrations. In the former case, I believe it was Terry Denton style-ish illustrations (like, black and white line drawings), whereas in the latter case it was full colour versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this question while trying to identify a series I myself had forgotten, and the mention of Terry Denton in your post lead me to what is likely the answer to yours (and certainly the answer to mine): the [**Storymaze** series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/337389-storymaze) by Terry Denton.

I don't have access to a copy right now, but it matches enough of the points you mentioned:

**someone called Nico (or potentially that's Nico from Pharesee)**

He's one of the main characters. From the description on Goodreads:

> Each high-energy tale follows the many surfing adventures of **Nico,
> Claudia, and Mikey** as they plunge into parallel worlds and weird
> places beyond the known universe.

**Ithaca (I think Ithaca was quite a significant place in these books)**

Ithaca is the planet that Nico, Claudia, and Mikey live on. (It was searching Ithaca on SE that led me here.)

**Medea in one of the books**

**the Clashing Rocks (potentially called "Holsteins" or "Holbeins" or "Hol-something"). A harpy (a little dragon like thing) was squashed between them.**

I don't recall Medea or the Clashing Rocks, but book 4 is named The Golden Udder so they're probably in there somewhere.

**I read this in mid-2000s.**

The books were released from 2001 to 2003, so that checks out.

**I seem to remember some books being mostly words with occasional illustrations, and some books having a lot more illustrations. In the former case, I believe it was Terry Denton style-ish illustrations (like, black and white line drawings), whereas in the latter case it was full colour versions.**

For the first book Goodreads has pages for both [the original version with full colour](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3604460-storymaze) and [the paperback version with prose](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3604458-storymaze-1). It seems the later books were in the prose and black-and-white illustration form only. You can see a couple of the full colour illustrations on [the Storymaze page on Terry Denton's website](https://www.terrydenton.com.au/books/storymaze), see if they ring a bell.

Comment: That's it! thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Potentially the Percy Jackson series by Rick Riordan. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percy_Jackson_%26_the_Olympians):

> Set in the mid-2000s, the series follows the story of Perseus "Percy" Jackson, a boy who discovers he is a demigod son of Poseidon. He was abandoned by his father because of an oath made by the Big Three (Zeus, Poseidon and Hades), the sons of Kronos, to not father any more children after World War II. The oath was sworn since the demigod children of the three gods are too powerful and have potential for great bloodshed (in-universe, World War II was a fight between children of the Big Three). Percy's journey turns even more electrifying when he discovers that numerous people and ancient monsters are trying to kill him due to his status as a demigod, latent strength, and growing influence in the Greek world.

I haven't read them but according to the fan wiki there was both a [Nico](https://riordan.fandom.com/wiki/Nico_di_Angelo) and [Medea](https://riordan.fandom.com/wiki/Medea), and the Clashing Rocks were the entrance to the [Sea of Monsters](https://riordan.fandom.com/wiki/Sea_of_Monsters#Entrance).

They weren't originally illustrated but there is certainly an [illustrated edition](https://www.readriordan.com/book/lightning-thief-illustrated-edition/).

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. It's not Percy Jackson but appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the droid your looking for: **Stickman Odyssey**

From [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0399254269):

> When Zozimos is banished by an **evil witch** (his stepmother!) from the **kingdom of Sticatha**-the kingdom he was next in line to rule-he trains at battle (if you call chasing after butterflies training), travels across stormy seas (thanks for that, Poseidon), slays golems and monsters (with a lot of help), charms beautiful women (not really), and somehow (despite his own ineptitude) survives quest after quest. By the love of Zeus, though, none of it brings him any closer to home!
>
> It does, however, make for one quirky, original, giggle-provoking graphic novel sure to appeal to any kid interested in Greek mythology, or merely looking for an entertaining read.
> *(emphasis mine)*

The evil witch might be who you think is Medea, and Sticatha is your Ithaca.

I haven’t read it, but according to [Penguin Random House](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/series/DVL/stickman-odyssey)

> A hilarious reinterpretation of Homer’s The Odyssey using stickman figures. Zozimos sails stormy seas, battles monsters, and defies the gods. Just another day in the life of a stickman.

The pictures are Terry Denton-like.

I can’t find anything about a Nico or Clashing rocks online, but they may be in the books.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think this is it thought, because it was published in 2011 and I definitely read this book in the early/mid 2000s.